# Error: 'TypeError: part.body.pipe is not a function' when uploading Buffer to Google Drive API"

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload a file to a folder on Google Drive. I can successfully upload local images, but I'm having trouble uploading a Buffer.

Essentially, I receive a dataUrl as a parameter and then convert it to a Buffer so that I can send it:

````
const templateBuffer = Buffer.from(order.template.split(',')[1], 'base64');
await drive.files.create({
    resource: {
        name: 'template.png',
        parents: [pedidoFolderId],
    },
    media: {
        mimeType: 'image/png',
        body: templateBuffer
    },
});```

However, I'm encountering an error: TypeError: part.body.pipe is not a function.
````

Comment: It needs to be a stream for the library I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
const stream = require("stream"); // Added
const templateBuffer = Buffer.from(order.template.split(',')[1], 'base64');
const res = await drive.files.create({
  resource: {
    name: "template.png",
    parents: [pedidoFolderId],
  },
  media: {
    mimeType: "image/png",
    body: new stream.PassThrough().end(templateBuffer), // Modified
  },
});
console.log(res.data);
```

- By this modification, when your client is valid and also the value of `templateBuffer` is a valid value of PNG image, the data is correctly uploaded to the folder `pedidoFolderId`.